# Does the type of lens adapter matter for manual focus?

Tags: lens, lens-design, manual-focus, lens-mount

**Context**

I use a cheap adapter that has an Aperture Ring for the new Nikon G lens but also works for older lens as well. I use a Sony a6000 which has focus peaking and related.

**Question**

Assuming that I **only** use manual focus for any Nikon lens, such as the Otus, is there any advantage on buying a more expensive adapter outside of EXIF data? Does this advantage also hold true when I use a lens that can auto focus (even if I only manual focus)? (I'm guessing manually focusing those lens are harder since the *throw distance* is shorter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What probably matters the most is how well the adapter is within tolerances. Anything you place between the lens and camera has the potential to tilt the optical axis of the lens relative to the camera's sensor plane. With modern high density sensors a misalignment of as little as 20µm has been demonstrated to be perceptible under standard viewing conditions. Having said this, there is no guarantee that a more expensive adapter that passes through lens information is built to higher tolerances than a cheaper one that does not.

Comment: I assume with tilt-shift adapters it is made to bend and "not" align?

Comment: Yes, that is what tilt-shift lenses or adapters do. But you need a lens with a much larger light circle than normal for a specific camera/sensor size in order to tilt and shift very far without getting substantial vignetting or even pushing the edge of the light circle into the frame. Normally a non-perpendicular field of focus is not desired.

Comment: Do you have example shots of bad/good adapters? I know what you're saying but as they say I'd rather see it in the shot.